# udp client server in pascal / delphi calling bind twice using synapse library (blcksock)

Tags: delphi, sockets, udp, bind, pascal

I know my way around C but I have existing code for a UDP client and server in Pascal using the synapse library. My questions are:
Client:
 - is it a good way to connect() to broadcast (instead of sendto())?

Server:
 - how is it possible to call bind() twice? (main question)
 - why would you bind() to the senderIP?

Regards

EDIT:
To clarify how this code is used:
There are multiple clients which try to send datapackets to the server. After the first packet of any of the clients arrives at the server, the server will from then on only accept data from this first client. Clients and server run on different machines.

Client:

```
UDPport:=TUDPblockSocket.Create;
UDPport.EnableBroadcast(true);
UDPport.Connect(cBroadcast,'1234');
while (not EOF(DATAfile)) do begin
  read(DATAfile,DATApacket);
  with (DATApacket) do begin
    NCOMport.SendBuffer(Addr(DATApacket),SizeOf(DATApacket));
  end;
end;
```

Server:

```
begin
  with TUDPblockSocket.Create do begin
    Bind(cAnyHost,'1234');
    AnyHost:=true;
    while (true) do begin
      if (WaitingData>0) then begin
        repeat
          buffer:=RecvPacket(c_UDPtimeout);
        until (WaitingData<=0);
        if (AnyHost) then begin
          SenderIP:=GetRemoteSinIP;
          Bind(SenderIP,'1234');
          AnyHost:=false;
        end else begin
          {extracting information out of the received data buffer}
        end;
      end;
    end;
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

with:

```
const  c_UDPtimeout  = 100;
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - is it a good way to connect() to broadcast (instead of sendto())?

You could.  All that really does for a UDP socket is statically sets the specified IP as the destination for outgoing packets so you can use `send()` instead of `sendto()`.

> - how is it possible to call bind() twice? (main question)

You cannot `bind()` a socket more than once. If you need to re-bind a socket, you have to close it first.  Your code example is basically binding the socket to the same port on all local IPs, then trying to re-bind it to just the first IP that receives any data on your port.

> - why would you bind() to the senderIP?

You wouldn't, and cannot, `bind()` to a remote IP.

Comment: Thanks,  
a) "...trying to re-bind it..." It seems to work in the code, so that is the only scenario where you are allowed to "re-bind" without first closing the socket?!  

b) "You wouldn't, and cannot, bind() to a remote IP"   But isn't that what `GetRemoteSinIP` does, getting the remote IP?

Comment: A) you **cannot** bind a socket that is already bound. Subsequent binds will fail. Period. B) yes, presumably `GetRemoteSinIP()` returns the remote IP. You cannot bind to that IP unless it is on the same machine, in which case you likely need to enable the socket's `SO_REUSEADDR`option to use it. Nothing in this code makes sense, without more info about the context in which it being used.

Comment: a) So the second bind should return an error?! But the program runs... b) Clients, Server run on different machines. See EDIT from initial question for more detail

Comment: Using `bind()` is not the way to restrict data flow from clients. All it can do is lock down which local network adapter data can be received on, but you still have to look at the remote IP of every packet received to make sure it comes from an authorized client before you use it. You do not need to re-bind for that. The code you showed is not set up for that.

Comment: Since you are sending files over UDP, you should use an actual file transfer protocol, like [Trivial FTP](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350) and related extensions.

Comment: all right, so the code is not really good / is faulty but strangely enough it still somehow works with no errors?! Any idea why? I hoped that there was something hiding in the synapse lib I didn't see...
(btw. I'm not really trying to send files, it's just reading data from a file and sends it)